# Which definition of 'lateral' applies?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> So removing Jesus from the cross alive was
>   not an accident on the part of the soldiers – they were following instructions.
>
> After examining the biblical evidence I have come to believe that Pontius Pilate was
>   responsible for saving Jesus, by some **lateral** interpretation of the facts and events as
>   laid out in biblical texts.

This is an adjective, so the aptest match is [Definition 1.2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lateral). Yet I still doubt this; there's nothing inventive?

Source: p 177, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage is *metaphorical*, so there's no literal reference to "sides" as per your definition 1.2. The relevant meaning is definition **2** in that link - *(chiefly British) Involving **lateral thinking**.*

> [**lateral thinking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_thinking)
>   *solving problems through an indirect and creative approach, using reasoning that is not immediately obvious and involving ideas that may not be obtainable by using only traditional step-by-step logic. The term was coined in 1967 by Edward de Bono.*

By extension, you can have "lateral" (creative, non-obvious) ***interpretations*** as well as lateral *thinking*.

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, it would never have occurred to me to suspect it was "chiefly British".  It seems common enough over here.  (I haven't tried to do any research into actual usage differences, although it wouldn't surprise me if there is *some* sort of difference.)

Comment: @snailboat: Comparing the "prevalence" values for ***lateral thinking*** in Google Books [BrE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lateral+thinking&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3B%2Cc0) and [AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lateral+thinking&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3B%2Cc0) suggests the usage is three times more common in the former. But I'd expect most "educated laymen" to know the term on both sides of the pond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers British books are just more highfalutin!

Comment: @Drew: I was just the right age to be fascinated by [Edward de Bono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_de_Bono) back in the 60s/70s, but he fell off my radar long before the Internet arrived. Twenty seconds skimming that Wikipedia link is the most he's penetrated my consciousness in decades, but it does make me wonder if maybe he went just a bit *too* far sideways. He hardly looks like a "mainstream thinker", anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thx. Didn't know about sideways EdB.

Comment: @Drew: like many such neologisms, it was [extra popular in its first decade](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lateral+thinking&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3B%2Cc0). But as that chart shows, it's steadily gained currency since the inevitable drop-off after that, when de Bono himself became less relevant (obviously, not just to me). So it's not a "failed coinage" like, say, [***semantic satiation***.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30331/2637)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It occurs to me that AmE speakers tend to use [*out-of-the-box* thinking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+the+box%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+out+of+the+box%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+lateral+thinking%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+lateral+thinking%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20box%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20box%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) in place of *lateral* thinking.

Comment: @Drew: That's got to be at least *possible*, I guess. But my initial reaction is adjectival *out-of-the-box* seems more "business jargon" than AmE as such. I don't know whether/how much NGram results are skewed by the inconsistent treatment of hyphenated phrases, but [*comparing the two*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+the+box+thinking%2Clateral+thinking&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20box%20thinking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clateral%20thinking%3B%2Cc0) does suggest ***lateral*** is far more common in this context.